# How can i create layout system with CEGUI?

Tags: user-interface

I've done little project that has scenes that i can change. Now i'm going to implement GUI using CEGUI. For each scene i want to use different layout and i want to create little wrapper that replaces layouts on screen change, so i don't need to implement something special in each scene to change layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found in one tutorial these lines:

```
CEGUI::Window *guiRoot = CEGUI::WindowManager::getSingleton().loadWindowLayout("TextDemo.layout");
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setGUISheet(guiRoot);
```

They've answered my question.